# Click once application rollback

Tags: deployment, clickonce, rollback

Is ClickOnce rollback possible?

How can I do that?

Does this application download all files on update?

How can I see which files are downloaded in the update?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly roll back a ClickOnce application. You can give the the old version a higher version number and redeploy/publish the application again. See also [How can I rollback clickOnce if I have a minimum required version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241541/how-can-i-rollback-clickonce-if-i-have-a-minimum-required-version)

Alternatively you can change the server side manifest file to point to the old version of the application as described here: [How can I roll-back a ClickOnce application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199348/how-can-i-roll-back-a-clickonce-application/1664121#1664121)

All files described in the application manifest file are downloaded when updating a ClickOnce application. The application manifest file has information about all the files in the ClickOnce application. I suggest reading the msdn site on [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

**Rollback**
If you don't specify a minimum required version, users have the ability to rollback **one** version via the Add/Remove Programs dialog. If you want to rollback the deployment on your server, you need to use all the old files with a new version number (just like @steenhulthin said).

**What is downloaded**
Only files that have changed are downloaded. ClickOnce hashes all your files and keeps that information in the application manifest (the one *without* the .application extension, go figure). If the overall ClickOnce version is newer on the server than on the client, it then compares individual file hashes to see what needs downloaded.

**What files are downloaded**
To see what files are downloaded, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It captures and displays http traffic and is pure awesome. Learn it. Use it. Love it.

Just an extra word of advice. If you're using Visual Studio to publish, stop. Using a tool like [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) takes more effort, but it helps you understand what the heck ClickOnce actually does. When it's boiled down, there's really not a lot to it. Using the Visual Studio publish wizard makes it seem like black magic.

Answer (score 0):

I understand ClickOnce version check algorythm as follows:

1. If version installed on client = version deployed to server - do nothing
2. If client version < server version - upgrade
3. If client version > server version:

   1. If minimumVersion specified on client >= server version - show error as we have
   2. If minimumVersion specified on client < server version - downgrade
   3. If minimumVersion is not specified on client - downgrade