# How to Rollback Click Once application by MageUI.exe in MS SDK

Tags: clickonce

Assume that, I publish Click Once app in shared folder. Newest version is 1.0.0.10, but now I want to rollback at version 1.0.0.5 .
I use MS .NET 4.0
Directory tree

[Publish Folder]
  -[Application Files]
        +[App_1_0_0_0]
        + ...
        +[App_1_0_0_5]
        + ...
        +[App_1_0_0_10]
  -Setup.exe
  -App.Application

Please help me, step by step with MageUI.exe

Comment: (Possible duplicate) I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199348/how-can-i-roll-back-a-clickonce-application

Answer (score 0):

If you are not publishing your updates as required (i.e. filling in the minimum version in the Updates dialog), then if you want to roll the users back, just copy the deployment manifest from the versioned folder to the top of the deployment folders, replacing the one that's there.

So take the one from App_1_0_0_5 and copy it to the top level of your deployment's folders.

Next time the user runs the application, it will see there is a different version, and it will install it.