# ClickOnce application manifest files

Tags: .net, deployment, tfs, msbuild, clickonce

I'm trying to get to a stage where I can rollback the version of a deployed ClickOnce application.  The highest rated answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199348/how-can-i-roll-back-a-clickonce-application) question seems to provide the solution.  However, when I look in my "Application Files" directory, I don't have a corresponding `[application name].application` file for each release.

If I drill down into the directory, I do have a file marked `[application name].manifest`.  However, this file seems to be different than the .application file in the parent directory.

So my question is twofold:

- Do I need [application name].manifest in order to replace the parent manifest file (if I simply take the .manifest and use that I get a deployment error.
- If I do then how can I get MSBuild to generate one?  My build script is as follows:

  ```
  MSBuild projectfile.csproj /target:publish /property:PublishDir=deployment_directory;PublishingURL=https://deployment_url
  ```

  Or, if this isn't possible (i.e. because my deployment process should be archiving the current one each deploy) is it possible to create / doctor one retrospectively?